# Is there an easy way to get the IP client using Deno.serveHttp?

Tags: javascript, ip, deno

I found this issue on the official repository. But instead of an straight way is more an implementation from oakserver. https://github.com/denoland/deno/discussions/9314

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cast the connection's address as a `Deno.NetAddr` and access the `hostname` (and `port` if you want) there:

```ts
const server = Deno.listen({ port: 8080 });

for await (const conn of server) {
  (async () => {
    const httpConn = Deno.serveHttp(conn);
    const { hostname } = conn.remoteAddr as Deno.NetAddr;
    for await (const requestEvent of httpConn) {
      requestEvent.respondWith(new Response(hostname));
    }
  })();
}
```

Comment: `hostname` is always `127.0.0.1` and `new Response(hostname)` does not give more useful data. I tried this on my laptop and the server production.

Comment: If you use `ipconfig` or something and learn your computer's IP address on your local network then you can load the page from another device (e.g. your phone); e.g. run the code with Deno and then (using your own computer's IP) access 192.168.86.222:8000 (or whatever your actual IP is) from your phone; you should see your phone's IP address displayed

Comment: you can also try this out on Deno Deploy; the following example uses `Deno.serveHttp` via the Deno standard library: https://dash.deno.com/playground/example-client-ip (see also https://deno.com/deploy/docs/examples#client-ip)

Comment: It was my fault with my nginx configuration. I needed to pass this header `proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;`